# Fontawesome 5 error on IE11

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-11, font-awesome, visual-web-developer

I have a problem with fontawesome on IE11 for some strange reason throws a javascript exception on this line:

```
var candidates = toArray(root.querySelectorAll(prefixesDomQuery))
```

It only happens on IE and with FA 5.1.1.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012, and I'm importing jQuery,Bootstrap, and Jqwidgets.

I've been searching a solution unsuccessfully.

I appreciate any help!

Thanks!